# Unable to mimick a Postman request in Python aiohttp

Tags: python, postman, aiohttp

I am trying to get [this Postman Collection](https://www.getpostman.com/collections/9df358c579df58d36d60) request to run in aiohttp but unable to do so. It runs in Postman well and shows data. You can use this url to test it yourself.

This is Python code I am trying to use.

```
async def test2():
    url = 'https://nationalpark.mahaonline.gov.in/User/Availability.aspx'
    data = {'__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$CPH$ddlUtility',
        '__VIEWSTATE': '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',
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '30B840D6',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION': '/wEdABDxLaaFMn9343OqJgSgkmjxBJ/H8P3kqyTkjExcLYtcGFBJ8C8BYpvL+GE7RwGpmWEbT9UBV3A0QjSyFpuERAlPsbNuBpZ6mIWONQrZ3y94fIpZ4AG8JMH0YPGdi4ZIQxS0Z2okfWoC/puMj/NjdYDmvnRn+BR1vSDA/QmOhf5Cm1ZompbG8uV7ojAwvWT4/lu9UBNS8pvWt/F8WfTFWsIJltHawDEmFvU8RGocPTDzHMIQY26emGcQb1cxpnNbPiTxr/HF2Dze+enlf8lhGijlUSZFPS/pmlFL9B08v8KulFPVXOa94et0GZgzkoqys5r/etgpEQvlbp40b8ZuEdj87EJXln9UnM2m0Lqiz0btC+gFkdY7fN74leFlSsHifgY=',
        'ctl00$CPH$ddlUtility:': '17',
        'ctl00$CPH$txtDate': '18/12/2018'
        }
    headers = {'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, data=data, headers=headers) as resp:
            html = await resp.read()
            await save_html(html)

async def save_html(html):
    os.remove("test3.html")
    with open("test3.html", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(html)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(test2())
```

The HTMLs returned are different in both cases. I have removed the cookies and headers from Postman so they are not the issue here.

I have also tried it doing with python requests and the request timedout.
I also tried it with http.client and it also timedout.

I might be missing something really basic here.

Comment: I get identical responses. Have you been IP banned?

Comment: Are you getting the schedule (a table with some entries)? Also since postman and the code are running on the same machine, IP might not be the issue here.

Comment: Found the error. ```ctl00$CPH$ddlUtility``` is having and extra colon.

Comment: Good catch, wow.